# CodeDom call a constructor

Tags: .net, constructor, codedom

How can I generate code which calls other class Constructor using CodeDom I can't find any CodeConstructorInvokeExpression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`CodeObjectCreateExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeobjectcreateexpression.aspx).